# My form data is not being displayed on html template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

i made a form and now i am  trying to to view the data from the form on the html template but its not working, any help would be helpful i just want the the data entered  through the the form to be displayed on the html page. Here is the code

> views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post
from.forms import TaskForm


def add_task(request):
    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST)
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'List/add_task.html', context)


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'List/home.html')


def task_list(request):
    context = {
        'posts': Post.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'List/task.html', context)
```

> models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Post(models.Model):
    Task = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='pythons')
    Detail = models.TextField(max_length=100, default='python')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

> forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .views import Post


class TaskForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

> task.html

```
{% extends "List/Home.html" %}
{% block content %}

    {% for post in posts %}

        <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
        <h3>{{ post.detail }}</h3>


    {% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

in your `Post` model you have fields name `Task` and `Detail` and in your template you are looking for field `title` and `detail`

Comment: it goes to show how dumb i can be anyway  thanks alot for the help